# Changing Image on hover based on title

Tags: jquery

Ok so I am trying to make 5 images change on hover based on their titles. I have a code, and it partly works, I believe I am not writing it correctly. So I am going to post two tries and hopefully someone will understand what I am trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var found = $('.user-basic-info img'); 
 found.filter('[src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png"]')
  .hover(function(){
 $(this).closest('img').replaceWith('<img alt="" src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png"/>');
 });
});



$(document).ready(function() { 
var found = $('.user-basic-info img'); 
 found.filter('[src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png"]')
  .hover(function(){
 $(this).closest('img').onMouseEnter('<img alt="" src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png"/>').onMouseOut('<img alt="" src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png"/>');
 });
}); //this code works partly as well, I just get no method of onMouseEnter
```

First time using hover effects to change image back and forth. I also need to be able to make this compatible to work with 5 other images so I would have to have variables for each "src" or rather title

To clarify one question for the `.filter` can we do the same for title? like so `[title="Founder"]` Just wondering because the above (about variables) I wanted to know if I could write...

`var a = $('.user-basic-info img').filter('[title="Founder"]');`

`var b = $('.user-basic-info img').filter('[title="Founder"]');`

Just wondering

Code I am using now::

```
$(function(){
var a = $('.user-basic-info img[title=Founder]');
var b = $('.user-basic-info img[title=Manager]');
var c = $('.user-basic-info img[title=Members]');
var d = $('.user-basic-info img[title=Technician]');
var e = $('.user-basic-info img[title=Moderator]');
var f = $('.user-basic-info img[title=Presidential]');
  $(div.post).hover(function() {
 a.attr('src','http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png');
  },
function() {
  a.attr('src','http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.user-basic-info img[title=Founder]').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).attr('src', "http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png"​);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr('src', "http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I love this code it's cleaner than mine by far. Can you explain to me a bit how the two functions work? I see you have a `.hover(function(){` then the next is just a `function()` never wrote like this so I'm clueless

Comment: the jQuery hover function can take two arguments (in function, out function): http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: hey Johhny what if I wanted to make the `('.post').hover(function(){` how would I write the next steps for making the image change? `a.attr()`?? added the jQuery I just worked up

Comment: Without seeing more code, I'm not sure what you want to do. See this jsfiddle for 2 examples of what I think you want. http://jsfiddle.net/5UUSN/2/

Comment: basically the img is in a div `.user-basic-info ` and that is inside a main div `.post` so if I hove `.post` I want the img I am calling to glow while the mouse is in that certain `.post` since there are alot it is a forum website

Answer (score 1):

`closest('img')` will never work, since images have no descendants. Remove it from the method chain:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<img alt="" src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png"/>');
```

If your ultimate goal is to toggle the src attribute on hover, just do that, instead of replacing the entire image:

```
$(this).attr('src','http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png');
```

It is possible to filter by the title attribute as well. The snippets you have posted should work correctly.

Comment: Thank Asad for answering my second question (I'm learning finally lol) I will try out the `$(this).replaceWith(` thank you give me like 2 minutes

Comment: ok so same thing happened to me, yes the `.attr('src','imgsrc.png');` is cleaner than what I originally posted. I need to make it so it returns to that img after.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img class=".user-basic-info" title="Founder" src="http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png">


$('.user-basic-info img[title=Founder]').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src','http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adming10.png');
},
function() {
    $(this).attr('src','http://i13.servimg.com/u/f13/17/83/35/07/adminn10.png');
});
```

Does something like this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6XMA/5/

Comment: haha you and Johnny Mopp posted at the same time the identical answers.